# CardUI in fragment can't use getView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was trying to open CardUI in fragment but it seems that getView() can't be used to execute CardUI component and also getActivity(). I couldn't find any other google like cards Library anywhere though.

The result of this give me out NullPointException on the mcardView

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        private WeakReference<Tab2Fragment> fragmentWeakRef;

        private MyAsyncTask (Tab2Fragment tab2Fragment) {
            this.fragmentWeakRef = new WeakReference<Tab2Fragment>(tab2Fragment);
        }
        private CardUI mCardView;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // init CardView
            Log.i("Page3","1st");
            try{
            mCardView = (CardUI) getView().findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
            if(mCardView == null){
                Log.i("Page3","Null");
                mCardView = (CardUI) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
            }

            Log.i("Page3","2nd");
            mCardView.setSwipeable(false);
}
}
}
```

How should I fix this?